# Relocate form created inside a previous form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two form classes (IHM and HelpPanel). In my first loaded form (IHM) I call the function `bHclass_Click` to create and load a HelpPanel. The `PopulatePCBclasses()` function basically creates all the controls that will be displayed.

My issue is that this HelpPanel is always displayed at the exact same location no matter what value is input in it's Location property.
I tried also by setting the Top and Left attributes but result was the same.

Do I miss an instruction?

```
private void bHclass_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HelpPanel hp = new HelpPanel();
    hp.PopulatePCBclasses();
    hp.Location = new Point(10, 500);
    hp.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the start position as manual before changing the location:

```
private void bHclass_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HelpPanel hp = new HelpPanel();
    hp.PopulatePCBclasses();
    hp.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    hp.Location = new Point(10, 500);
    hp.Show();
}
```

Comment: Hi Isma, Thanks for this answer. It worked perferctly !